# equating same column from the same table in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

probably it's a silly question but i'm really struggling to understand the below SQL query.

So i'm doing this exercise:  *What are the codeNames of the spies who have no less amountDue than the 
the average of amountDue for spies with the same spymaster?*

The table is as shown below:

```
codeName    firstName   lastName    dateOfBirth gender  mark                amountDue   spymaster   bankAccount
007         James       Bond        01-12-72    M       Mole on chin        5050        Q        23456
bud         Fanny       Charleston  31-07-83    F       Scar on cheek       25.67       Q        34567
freddie     John        Smith       05-05-54    M       One finger missing  312.5       M        45678
```

the code used to solve this problem is:

```
select codeName 
from Spy as S1
where amountDue >= 
  (select avg(amountDue) 
  from Spy as S2 
  where S1.spymaster = S2.spymaster)
```

what i don't understand is the condition in the WHERE clause. Grateful if someone can explain that bit for me.

Thanks,
Mo

Answer (score 2):

```
select codeName 
from Spy as S1 --outer 
where amountDue >= 
  (select avg(amountDue) 
  from Spy as S2  --inner 
  where S1.spymaster = S2.spymaster)
```

when executes above two lines you will get all codename from spy but when you applied condition where amountDue is greater than equal to your retrieving avg of amount where s1 and s2 spymaster is same. Means your checking outer values with inner values.and when values will be same those Codename will get display.

What I understood I shared with you,If you got any more information on this let me know,it's helpful for me !.

Comment: Thanks @Sandesh. I understand that logic, what i don't understand is the inner WHERE condition. why use are using (where S1.spymaster = S2.spymaster)

Comment: they are comparing outer table to inner table using spymaster column.means s1.spymaster and s2.spymaster when both will equal then those related amountDue will combine and find the avg of that amountDue and compare with outer where conditin.when condition satisfied those codename will get display !

Comment: ok cool, thanks. But let's get back to the question for a minute: _What are the codeNames of the spies who have no less amountDue than the the average of amountDue_ **for spies with the same spymaster?**. so the question clearly wants to compare the amountDue against the average of spies reporting to the same spymaster (at least that's my understanding). After testing the second nested SQL query in isolation, the query averages all amountDue regardless of which spymaster the spy reports to. right? shouldn't we average only the amounts related to particular spymaster?

Comment: as per the query you are comparing with  amountDue is greater than or equal to avg of amount due of spymaster.when amountDue is greater than Avg of amountdue those CodeName will get display.